# How to Change Usernames in Password Store en Masse

Tags: sed

I have been using [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org) for to store my passwords via GPG. I am trying to change an old username to a new username in dozens of accounts all at once.

Each username is in a "Username:" comment under the password. i.e. a gpg encrypted file `~/.password-store/amazon` is like the following:

```
password123
Username: old_account@protonmail.com
URL: amazon.com
OTP: ...
```

I can't just replace all occurrences of the old username, because sometimes the username appears in other comments. One such example is in OTP codes. This seems like a relatively simple problem, I just don't want to run the risk of clobbering all occurrences of the old username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following command:

```
sed -i 's/^\(Username: \) *old_account@protomail.com$/\1new_account@protomail.com/' *
```

This command replaces in each file each line that starts with "Username: old_account@protomail.com" and replaces it with "Username: new_account@protomail.com"

Note: Make a backup before playing with this command because it replaces the original files with new ones. This is the "-i" option of the "sed" command.